# restart a container when reaches memory limit in plain docker-compose (not kubernetes)

Tags: docker, memory, docker-compose

i have tried like this

```
sample:
    container_name : sample
    mem_limit: 1000m
    restart: always
```

but container is never exceeding limit instead stuck between 999 and 998 and is not triggering out of memory.

Comment: What is the process in the container actually doing?  It's possible for a process to discover the container memory limit (modern Java virtual machines use this to set the heap size, for example) and it's possible that the runtime is intentionally staying under that limit.